# C++ Segmentation fault while trying to create a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, segmentation-fault

I want to create a vector of vectors in C++ with dimensions nx2 where n(rows) is given by user. I am trying to insert values in this vector using a for loop but As soon as give the value of n(rows), it gives a Segmentation fault error
What to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#define col 2
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row;
    cin >> row;
    vector<vector<int>> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)

            cin >> vec[i][j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know it's empty after this construction, right?

Comment: `vec[0][0]` is out of bounds, because `vec` is empty.

Comment: You’ll need to either resize() the parent vector and each sub vector (preferable, since you have the information) or push_back(), which will work, but not be quite as efficient.

Comment: So how can i resize each sub vector for example I added one line "vec.resize(row)" now what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `resize` a vector before inserting elements.  Or use `push_back` to insert incrementally.

```
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    vec.resize(row);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        vec[i].resize(col);

        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        {
            cin >> vec[i][j];
        }
    }
```

OR:

```
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    vec.resize(row);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            vec[i].push_back(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of answering obvious dupes? If you think the dupe I've linked to is not good enough, you could find another one - we should have many of them here.

Comment: @Evg - if you can find a duplicate question and do the "vote to close" thing, I'll close it with you.

Comment: I've already found at least one dupe and was going to add another one to the list, but you've reopened the question for some reason.

Comment: What was the link to your dupe again?  I thought it was a link to the generic "how to solve a segmentation fault" question.  Where in this case, it's clearly a lesson needed on how to resize a vector.

Comment: Share the link here and if I think it's really the same question, I'll delete this answer and close it with you.